# Error: Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(Error performing getDocuments, INVALID_ARGUMENT)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to update a document field after the user performs a certain action. Here is my code:

```
          _title = data["postTitle"];
          _content= data["postContent"];
          Firestore.instance.collection("Social_Posts")
              .where("postTitle", isEqualTo: _title)
              .where("postContent", isEqualTo: _content).getDocuments()
              .then((event) {
              Firestore.instance
                  .collection("Social_Posts")
                  .document(event.documents[0].documentID)
                  .updateData({"views" : FieldValue.increment(1),}).then((value){});
          });
```

When I run this code, I get the error: Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(Error performing getDocuments, INVALID_ARGUMENT: value for postContent is too large to be used in a query, null)

This error only occurs when my document field is too large. How do I fix this issue and perform the query?

Comment: The fix is obviously to place limits on what you can pass to `where`, or find another way of locating the document you want to update. I don't think it's any more complicated than that.  Searching for documents using very large strings seems like not a very good thing to do.

Comment: Hey @DougStevenson, is there any documentation about this? I can't find anything, and I am having the same problem.